# Evitar caracteres especiales en las rutas

Tags: url, angular, ascii

Estoy contruyendo un filtrado para un proyecto, uno de los filtros se llena de este arreglo:

```
this.grupoHorario = ['Todos', 'Madrugada', 'Mañana', 'Tarde', 'Noche'];
```

Cuando el usuario selecciona **Mañana** la ruta que me muestra la consola es la siguiente:

> http:/localhost:7001/menor/estado?fechaInicio=1521650664995&fechaFin=1521650664995&grupoHorario=**Ma%C3%B1ana**

Alguna solucion para que en la opción del filtro siga saliendo **Mañana** pero a la URL no codifique el caracter especial.
Esta seria una buena solucion pero no logro encontrar la manera.

> http:/localhost:7001/menor/estado?fechaInicio=1521650664995&fechaFin=1521650664995&grupoHorario=**Manana**

**EDITADA**
HTML

```
<div>
   <label>Grupo horario:</label>
     <div class="form-group">
       <ng-select [allowClear]="true" [items]="grupoHorario" 
         (selected)="seleccionarGrupoHorario($event)" placeholder="Seleccione">
       </ng-select>
     </div>
  </div>

Funcion seleccionarGrupoHorario()
  seleccionarGrupoHorario(valor: any): void {
    this.valorGrupoHorario= valor;
}
```

**Luego se guarda en el localStorage**

```
this.myLocalStorageService.setItem(Items.GRUPO_HORARIO, this.valorGrupoHorario);
```

**Y luego se contruye la URL llamando elementos del localStorage**

```
let grupoHorario= this.myLocalStorageService.getItem(Items.GRUPO_HORARIO);  
let globalUrl = "?fechaInicio=" + fechaInicio + "&fechaFin=" + fechaFn + "&grupoHorario=" + grupoHorario
```

Comment: Como es la forma de selección? Ya que tu valor visual podría ser uno y el valor a nivel código, otro.

Comment: Si mostraras como generas la url podriamos ayudarte.

Comment: Y porque mejor antes de leer la variable le haces un url decode

Answer (score 0):

Lo siento pero no es posible mostrar ***Mañana*** en la url y si quieres que se vea *Manana* en vez de *Mañana* creo de puedes hacerlo tu mismo considerando que no nos entregaste la código que lee los filtros.

En lo que si te puedo ayudar es guiándote con este tema, cuando envías un string con caracteres especiales o *caracteres reservados*, lo que debes hacer es codificar primero el string con uno de los siguientes métodos de javascript:

```
var str = "Mañana";
var strParaEnviar = encodeUri(str); // decodificador -> decodeURI(str) 
// o encoeURIComponent(str); decodificador decodeURIComponent(str)
// o escape(str); decodificador unescape(str);
```

También debes saber que si vas a leer esto en el lado del servidor, debes decodificarlo acorde a la codificación que utilizaste, cada lenguaje tiene su propio decodificador pero todos tienen decodificadores para estos métodos.

Comment: Intente con las 3 formas de codificación que me dices. Codificando el string ante de guardarlo y decodificandolo antes de usarlo, pero en los 3 casos en la url me muestra  _undefined_

Comment: oh debías mandar el `str` como parámetro, mi error